# What is the usecase of calling hana::is_valid with a nullary function?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae, boost-hana

[Boost.Hana](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html) offers [`boost::hana::is_valid`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1type.html#a2d2e7e08e284f7e0bd1bd9c3ad0e0a2b) to check whether a SFINAE-friendly expression is valid.

You can use it like this

```cpp
    struct Person { std::string name; };
    auto has_name = hana::is_valid([](auto&& p) -> decltype((void)p.name) { });
    Person joe{"Joe"};
    static_assert(has_name(joe), "");
    static_assert(!has_name(1), "");
```

However, there's a note about the argument to `is_valid` being a nullary function:

> To check whether calling a nullary function `f` is valid, one should use the `is_valid(f)()` syntax. […]

How can I even use it by passing to it a nullary function? I mean, if a function is nullary, then how is its body gonna have any dependent context to which SFINAE can apply?

I think that maybe "lambda captures" might have something to do with the answer, but I can't really figure it out how.

Comment: Even if the function had one or more parameters, it wouldn't imply having dependent context; (at least one of the) parameters would have to be templated. So in this respect a nullary function is no different than one with arguments. The documentation just puts emphasis on calling syntax. Regarding on **where/how** SFINAE actually happens check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use case is that of checking that `f` is actually nullary, e.g

```cpp
if constexpr (is_valid(f)()) {
  f(); // Treat f as a "no args function"
} else if constexpr (is_valid(f, arg1)) {
  f(arg1);
}
```

what the documentation says is that unlike functions of non zero arity, the `is_valid` predicate can only be invoked in the form:

```
is_valid(f)(); // Invoking "is_valid(f)", i.e. no parentheses, does NOT
               // check that f is a nullary function.
```

reminder: to check whether e.g. a 2 arguments function call is valid you can say:

```
is_valid(f, arg1, arg2);
// or 
is_valid(f)(arg1, arg2)
```

Take for example the following [**Demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/4sss5cEfv)

```cpp
void f0()
{
    std::cout << "Ok f0\n";
}

void f1(int)
{
    std::cout << "Ok f1\n";
}

template <class F>
void test(F fun)
{
    if constexpr (hana::is_valid(fun)())
    {
        fun();
    }
    else if constexpr (hana::is_valid(fun, 2))
    {
        fun(2);
    }
}

int main() {

    test(f0);
    test(f1);
}
```

It may be obvious, but you have to keep in mind that SFINAE does not happen ON `f0` or `f1`. SFINAE happens in the [guts of `is_valid`](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/type.hpp#L130) between the different flavors of `is_valid_impl` (comments mine):

```cpp
// 1
template <
    typename F, typename ...Args, typename = decltype(
    std::declval<F&&>()(std::declval<Args&&>()...)
)>constexpr auto is_valid_impl(int) { return hana::true_c; }

// 2
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
constexpr auto is_valid_impl(...) { return hana::false_c; }

// Substitution error on 1 will trigger version 2
```

So your question

> "I mean, if a function is nullary, then how is its body gonna have any dependent context to which SFINAE can apply?"

has little meaning since SFINAE does not happen on the user provided function. After all, we are setting up nothing to enable SFINAE on **our** functions. Implementing SFINAE requires to provide more than 1 candidates that "guide" the instantiation process (check [SFINAE sono buoni](http://www.stevedewhurst.com/once_weakly/w02_SFINAE.pdf)).

**The term "SFINAE friendly" here, has to do with `f` (our function) being usable as type parameter for the SFINAE implementation in `is_valid`**. For example, if in our [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ws5ao91MK) `f` was overloaded (replace `f1(int)` with `f0(int)`) you would get a substitution error:

```
<source>:22:6: note: candidate: 'template<class F> void test(F)'
   22 | void test(F fun)
      |      ^~~~
<source>:22:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

because when the compiler reaches the deepest point of `is_valid_impl` it tries to instantiate the favorable version (version 1, that doesn't have `...` parameter) but it cannot tell what the type of `F` is and produces a hard error.

For reference, the way SFINAE works is that if it could use type `F`, the compiler would:

1. make an attempt on version `1`
2. If successfull return `true` (so IT IS valid)
3. If not successfull it would go for version `2` (substitution error is not a failure) which does not use type `F` as `F(Args...)` and hence produce a `false`.